# Split values by comma vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have below string and I try below sample output using comma split function in VB.net but no luck.

This is my Code which I tried:

```
Sub Main()
   Dim testString as String="1,1,PATRONAGE 
       DISTRIBUTIONS,A00001PATR01,N/A,N/A,ZZ 
       1000001,1000001,7,N/A,7,S63,"$6,411.88 ","$6,411.88 ",$0.00 ,Customer 
       1,,82327 330TH 
       ST,,ELLENDALE,MN,560264012,Yes,Yes,1000001,2/15/2018,Batch 
       1,PAT 01,1.82E+11,75911603,"$24,761.32 ",$0.00 ,"$24,761.32 
       ",100%,N/A,"$3,845.08 ",$648.22 ,"$3,845.08 ",100%,N/A,"$3,062.66 
       ",$0.00 
       ,$0.00 ,0%,N/A,"$4,069.99 ",$0.00 ,$0.00 ,0%,N/A,"$4,718.86 ",$0.00 
       ,$0.00 
       ,0%,N/A,"$6,259.78 ",$0.00 ,$0.00 ,0%,N/A,"$5,933.43 ",$0.00 ,$0.00 
       ,0%,N/A,"$12,178.72 ",$0.00 ,$0.00 ,0%,N/A,"$13,980.26 ",$0.00 ,$0.00 
       ,0%,N/A,"$5,763.66 ","$5,763.66 
       ","$5,763.6",100%,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,Coming 
       Summer 2018,"$84,573.76 ","$6,411.88 ","$34,370.06 ",41%,N/A,"$34,370.06""

   Dim strElements() As String = Split(testString,",$")
   Console.WriteLine("1. " & strElements(0))
   For i As Integer = 1 To strElements.Count - 1
       Console.WriteLine((i + 1).ToString & ". $" & strElements(i))
   Next

   Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Input:

```
1,1,PATRONAGE DISTRIBUTIONS,A00001PATR01,N/A,N/A,ZZ 
1000001,1000001,7,N/A,7,S63,"$6,411.88 ","$6,411.88 ",$0.00 ,Customer 
1,,82327 330TH ST,,ELLENDALE,MN,560264012,Yes,Yes,1000001,2/15/2018,Batch 
1,PAT 01,1.82E+11,75911603,"$24,761.32 ",$0.00 ,"$24,761.32 
",100%,N/A,"$3,845.08 ",$648.22 ,"$3,845.08 ",100%,N/A,"$3,062.66 ",$0.00 
,$0.00 ,0%,N/A,"$4,069.99 ",$0.00 ,$0.00 ,0%,N/A,"$4,718.86 ",$0.00 ,$0.00 
,0%,N/A,"$6,259.78 ",$0.00 ,$0.00 ,0%,N/A,"$5,933.43 ",$0.00 ,$0.00 
,0%,N/A,"$12,178.72 ",$0.00 ,$0.00 ,0%,N/A,"$13,980.26 ",$0.00 ,$0.00 
,0%,N/A,"$5,763.66 ","$5,763.66 ","$5,763.6",100%,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,Coming 
 Summer 2018,"$84,573.76 ","$6,411.88 ","$34,370.06 ",41%,N/A,"$34,370.06"
```

Output:

```
1
1
PATRONAGE DISTRIBUTIONS
N/A
N/A
$10,250
$10,000
$1200
etc
```

How to build the above output? Is there any regex to split the values and build above output ?

Comment: You want to ignore strings like `A00001PATR01,ZZ,1000001,1000001`  because your sample output doesn't include them?

Comment: Thats ok.. but that s sample ouput ..I want to above output ..actually how can i split those input string by comma or dollar to get the output? problem is that input string contains dollar amount with normal text ( ie with out dollar )

Comment: Your question is unclear, `but no luck.` What did you tried so far? what's the error you got when you use `Strings.Split`?

Comment: Firstly, how can we possibly tell you how to write code to achieve a result based on a single example that doesn't even make sense? If you want to write code that can handle any input then you have to know what the rules are for all cases, which you have made exactly zero effort to convey to us. Secondly, even if you did tell us what the rules are, we're not here to write your code for you. If you can't make an attempt for yourself then you have tried hard enough. Do some research, make an effort and then, if you encounter an actual issue, post back with all the relevant information.

Comment: If you're thinking of posting code of any significant length in a comment then think again. Edit your original post to make it a proper question. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what constitutes a proper question for this site.

Comment: ok thanks jmcilhinney  .. i updated my post now .. and i hope u can understand my question.

Comment: If you want to split each String by comma, **don't put** comma on digits like `$10,250` it will split the number into Two(2):

Comment: Yes ..Thats my problem...I want the text and also whole amount "$10,250" too

Comment: The DELIMITER that you use should be UNIQUE within the string, so that DATA cannot be mistaken for a delimiter. Try changing your delimiter to something like a rarely use character such as cart (^) or a pipe character (|) And split your data string into the array using THAT delimiter....

Answer (score 0):

Change Your input from:

> 1,1,PATRONAGE DISTRIBUTIONS,A00001PATR01,N/A,N/A,ZZ 
>   1000001,1000001,7,N/A,7,S63,"$6,411.88 ","$6,411.88 ",$0.00 ,Customer 
>   1,,82327 330TH
>   ST,,ELLENDALE,MN,560264012,Yes,Yes,1000001,2/15/2018,Batch  1,PAT
>   01,1.82E+11,75911603,"$24,761.32 ",$0.00 ,"$24,761.32 
>   ",100%,N/A,"$3,845.08 ",$648.22 ,"$3,845.08 ",100%,N/A,"$3,062.66
>   ",$0.00  ,$0.00 ,0%,N/A,"$4,069.99 ",$0.00 ,$0.00 ,0%,N/A,"$4,718.86
>   ",$0.00 ,$0.00  ,0%,N/A,"$6,259.78 ",$0.00 ,$0.00 ,0%,N/A,"$5,933.43
>   ",$0.00 ,$0.00  ,0%,N/A,"$12,178.72 ",$0.00 ,$0.00 ,0%,N/A,"$13,980.26
>   ",$0.00 ,$0.00  ,0%,N/A,"$5,763.66 ","$5,763.66
>   ","$5,763.6",100%,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,Coming   Summer 2018,"$84,573.76
>   ","$6,411.88 ","$34,370.06 ",41%,N/A,"$34,370.06"

To below, (replacing all delimiters with PIPE symbol and stripping out quotes)

> 1|1|PATRONAGE DISTRIBUTIONS|A00001PATR01|N/A|N/A|ZZ
>   1000001|1000001|7|N/A|7|S63|$6,411.88 |$6,411.88 |$0.00 |Customer
>   1||82327 330TH
>   ST||ELLENDALE|MN|560264012|Yes|Yes|1000001|2/15/2018|Batch 1|PAT
>   01|1.82E+11|75911603|$24,761.32 |$0.00 |$24,761.32|100%|N/A|$3,845.08
>   |$648.22 |$3,845.08 |100%|N/A|$3,062.66|$0.00|$0.00 |0%|N/A|$4,069.99
>   |$0.00 |$0.00 |0%|N/A|$4,718.86 |$0.00|$0.00|0%|N/A|$6,259.78 |$0.00
>   |$0.00 |0%|N/A|$5,933.43 |$0.00 |$0.00|0%|N/A|$12,178.72 |$0.00 |$0.00
>   |0%|N/A|$13,980.26 |$0.00 |$0.00|0%|N/A|$5,763.66
>   |$5,763.66|$5,763.6|100%|N/A|N/A|N/A|N/A|N/A|Coming Summer
>   2018|$84,573.76 |$6,411.88 |$34,370.06 |41%|N/A|$34,370.06|

Change your line:

Dim strElements() As String = Split(testString,",$")

To the line below:

Dim strElements() As String = Split(testString,"|")